# Rsync sync two folders with a filetype

Tags: centos, rsync

There is a serverA with a folder folder1, in folder1 there are different files: `bar.htm`, `test.jpg`, `test2.jpg`, `foo.txt`, `folder1/subfolder1/test3.jpg`, etc.

There is a serverB with an empty folder2

I want to constantly sync `*.jpg` files from serverA to serverB, so that serverB will have test.jpg and test2.jpg, test3.jpg and other .jpg files it can find in subdirectories of the serverA.

Also, I want it work automatically, without requesting password prompt.

Two CentOS servers. I understand that it is best to use rsync, cron, but how should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
for f in `find . -name "*.jpg"`; do rsync $f serverB: ; done
```

You need to then run it on account that has SSH key with blank password to accessing the serverB.

Note: This fails if files are removed. If you want files deleted from serverB when they are deleted from serverA, then you need to change this.